# ZMPT101B module producing VDC even with AC source disconnected

Tags: ac, power-electronics, dc, esp32

I am trying to use ZMPT101B to measure 110V AC but even after calibration and using multiple sketches when I power off my AC source it measures some AC voltage (or in other words a signal is still being generated by the module).

When calibrated it does measure 120V but when I tested the output signal of the ZMPT101B module (bought from Amazon) the VDC between signal and GND is still 3.0 Volts with AC supply shut off and its happening with other modules as well.
Here is the module: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BM5KR4R3?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BM5KR4R3)

I have tried these scenarios:
ESP32 powered separately and ZMPT101B powered with external power source with common ground
ESP32 and ZMPT101B both powered via USB from PC (ZMPT101B powered by 5V out on ESP32)

Am I doing something very basic wrong here?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm having the same problem.
Have a ZMPT101B connected to an Arduino Uno reading 230V AC. All ok with power on but when AC is switched off I still get a reading of ~70V.
I'm assuming it's something obvious but I just can't see it.